# EF or SQL Server - Computed / Continous Column

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm not sure how to do this and where it should be implemented.

I have a table with columns: `ID, TypeID, AIndex`. Both the `ID` and `TypeID` are supplied when creating a new record. The `AIndex` is a continuous column based on both IDs.

To illustrate here an example:

```
ID  TypeID  Aindex  
---------------------
1   1       1
1   1       2
1   2       1
1   3       1
2   1       1
2   1       2
```

Comment: How exactly is the value supposed to go into Aindex determined?

Comment: It should be calculated, if there's already a record with that id and type id then increment + 1.

Answer (score 0):

The big question is:

**They are lot of people writing to this table at a time?**

When you compute `Aindex` column from previous database data, some thing like `max( Aindex ) + 1` the risk is to **induce locks**.

If only few inserts are made in table you can write increment code in your favorite layer, EF or DB. But if your table has high write ratio you should search for a alternate technique like **counters table** or something else. You can keep this counters table with EF if you want.